# use two asynctask and replace the first with the second activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

class activity and splash.class. In the first (which execute the main program), has asynctask (it will be call several time) retrieving data. The second activity is a splash screen which run until the data are downloaded.

```
public class splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    startHeavyProcessing();

}

private void startHeavyProcessing(){
    new LongOperation().execute("");
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        startActivity(i);

        return "";
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() {}
}
}
```

I would like to finish spalash activity, when MainActivity finished to retrieve data in its doInBackground. Once done, I would run MainActivity only.

Comment: Call `splash.this.finish()` in `onPostExecute` method to finish spalash and call   `startActivity(i);`  also in `onPostExecute` instead of `startActivity ` before calling `splash.this.finish()`

Comment: i will suggest you to put everything in splash activity, handle every thing in splash Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    return "";
}


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

if(result != null){
}
 Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
}else {
Log.e("DOWNLOAD ERRO");
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

}

protected void onProgressUpdate() {}
}
```